# The impact of creating a controller function with and without angular.module().controller() in angular?

Tags: angularjs

In the Angular documentation there are two examples of creating a controller:

```
function GreetingController($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}
```

and

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

Both are used in the markup:

```
<div ng-controller="GreetingController">
  {{ greeting }}
</div>
```

My question is, what are the advantages of using the angular.module().controller() method?

Comment: For one, it's **modul**ar (: It's easier to reuse and share between projects...

Comment: `function GreetingController(){}` goes in the global scope whereas `myApp.controller(...)` lives in the module you created. As @Sasxa points out, this makes the latter more modular and therefore better for all of the standard reasons that aren't only Angular-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A controller is basically a function. In the first case you can reuse the function over all your applications(global scope function) and not bind it to one.

The second case actually attaches the controller to an application(application scope), allowing you to pass not only a function but an array that includes strings in case you want to minify your javascript files.

Comment: Just beat me with the minify note. I think that should be emphasised for anyone building an angular app.

Comment: Regarding your first point, you might note that `module().controller`'s can be reused as well. For instance, you could group controllers into a module and inject them into more than one app. Using the global space is just more quick and dirty (with emphasis on the dirty :) ).

Comment: You can also invoke private functions outside of their class in C# using reflection..dirty will stay dirty :)..

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason for the array of strings for arguments is so they will not be minified.  If $scope were minified with the letter a, Angular would not know to inject $scope as a dependency?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Read more here: http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications/